# Crash Msg: Unable to generate a temporary class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a client-server application. The installation at server is working well. However, at the client, I got the error above when it's Assembly.Loadfile( file on a server machine)...

More details: code is quite simple:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"driveonserver\\mydll.dll");

Type typ = assembly.GetType("mycontrol", false);

object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typ);
```

came out error message: value can not be null. Parameter name:type

> Crash Msg: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
>   error CS0006: Metadata file '//driveonserver\mydll.dll");
>
> [12/01/2012][17:18]: Exception Type: System.InvalidOperationException
>   [12/01/2012][17:18]: Crash Source: System.Xml

Comment: try disabling AV, if you have it. I've seen it cause issues with this type of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

When you are loading a DLL from a server, you must have [loadFromRemoteSources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252%28VS.100%29.aspx) enabled in your app.config:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks. My issues here there are a bunch of dlls, so I need to find a way to manage this situation. Also the exe is not in the same folder of those dlls.

Comment: This config entry should enable remote loading for all DLLs. I would give it a try to see if it works and, if it doesn't, it will probably come back with a different exception.

Comment: You are right, after a couple of days trying. I can confirm your point is correct. Howwever, I have more issues related to the application as a whole.

Comment: My project has two parts. One is exe file created from another team. I have bunch of dlls for the functions.  Now add this config to the app.exe.config. the calling from application to our dlls is working. however, once in my functions (code), it still complain about the dll in the network share folder is not found. Because the exe folder and all those my dlls are not in the same folder. Do I need to indicate in the config file those dll folder should also loadfromremotesources enable = true, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

found [this](http://forum.dotnetpanel.com/forums/p/2619/14403.aspx) ...

> giving IIS_WPG for IIS 6.0/ IIS_IUSRS for IIS 7.0 and above; modify access on C:\Windows\Temp seems to have solved the problem.

this works for ASP.Net, by the way. Not quite tested for windows applications.